# How to access a query with a dependant range of cells

Tags: sql, excel, connection, vba

this function opens a connection to a an sql database, collects data and bring it back and copies it into cell O6 and onward.  I have come into two problems.  My first is i want to select a range of cells in which to query with.  The range starts at I6, and goes to cell I"lastrow" which the last cell that contains data i want to query.

1. i do not know what to say in my query:

   ```
   where s.cusip = ""
   ```

and 2. it tells me that there is a user defined-type not defined.

Any help is greatly appreciated

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Call datacollect_alternate ' my code

End Sub

Public Sub datacollect_alternate()

 Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
 Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
 Dim i_date As String
 cmd.ActiveConnection = OpenConnectionDPDMView

 cmd.CommandText = "select s.description, s.rate coupon, sa.rrb_factor from dpdm.security s left join dpdm.security_analytics sa on s.security_id = sa.security_id where s.cusip= '" & Range("i6").Value & "' And sa.as_of_date = trunc(sysdate)"
 Set rs = cmd.Execute
'Declare variables'
Dim Lastrow As Integer
'Lastrow = Cells(Cells.rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
Lastrow = Range("c65336").End(xlUp).Row

'Copy Data to Excel'
    ActiveSheet.Range("O6").CopyFromRecordset rs

copy_cells (Lastrow)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your WHERE Clause you could try something like this:

```
dim sWhereClause as string
dim iRow as integer

sWhereClause = "where s.cusip IN ('"

for irow=6 to LastRow
    sWhereClause =sWhereClause & range("I" & irow).text & "','"      
next

debug.print sWhereClause ' output to Immediate window

sWhereClause =left(sWhereClause ,len(sWhereClause)-2) ' to remove the last comma and quote
sWhereClause =    sWhereClause & ")" ' close the IN bracket
```

so append the string `sWhereClause` onto your SQL Query and start debugging!

On what line are you getting the error?

Comment: I edited the code in the question, I found the problem in the query so it works now, but this is only for the one line, ill use your suggestion and see if i can get it working,

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub datacollect_alternate()

 Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
 Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
 Dim i_date As String
 Dim Lastrow As Integer
 Dim sWhereClause As String
 Dim iRow As Integer

 Lastrow = Range("I65336").End(xlUp).Row
 cmd.ActiveConnection = OpenConnectionDPDMView


 For iRow = 6 To Lastrow
     sWhereClause = "where s.cusip= '"
     sWhereClause = sWhereClause & Range("I" & iRow).Value

     cmd.CommandText = "select s.description, s.rate coupon, sa.rrb_factor from dpdm.security s left join dpdm.security_analytics sa on s.security_id = sa.security_id " & sWhereClause & "' And sa.as_of_date = trunc(sysdate)"
     Set rs = cmd.Execute

    'Copy Data to Excel'
    ActiveSheet.Range("O" & iRow).CopyFromRecordset rs

 Next



 copy_cells (Lastrow)

End Sub
```